# How does PopCorn Time iOS installer work?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, jailbreak

I am all against piracy and I know that PopCorn Time as a service is illegal but what I am curious about is that they have managed to come out with an app for iOS that lets you install even on non jailbroken devices.

How does that work out?

[Popcorn Time For iOS Released, No Jailbreak Required](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-popcorn-time-for-ios-without-jailbreak/)

Comment: I think it does not install apps - just movies etc

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 7 (beta), Apple has released free iOS provisioning profiles for all: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html

Which means you can now install arbitrary iOS applications through a computer onto an iOS device without having to purchase a license from Apple, without having it to be approved by Apple, and without needing specific provisioning profiles installed on the device.

I'm guessing they're just using this to their advantage.

Comment: Xcode only works on a Mac, whereas iOS installer works on Windows as well.

Comment: And according to this YouTube video, they dont even use Xcode to achieve that.
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZ42KBeVMMY)

Comment: @CaptainBlack that doesn't stop people from communicating to Apple servers and simulating what Xcode would do.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the developers of Popcorn Time have a side project called [iOS Installer](http://iosinstaller.com).

For technical details and questions, you can e-mail them on osinstaller.team@gmail.com.

As for how this will work out, probably not well. Apple is unlikely to relinquish control over app distribution on iOS devices.